# Iframe is not loading the URL provided

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I have an asp.net MVC5 app deployed in a IIS server and running from **http://x.x.x.x/app**. I have a view called Geocatalog which contains an iframe in where I want to embed Geonetwork(deployed in tomcat9) which runs in the same server (**http://x.x.x.x:PORT/geonetwork**) but when executing in the navigator I have this error :

```
Refused to frame 'http://x.x.x.x:PORT/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

I don't know why is this happening? I did the exact same thing with another url and it worked well.

**Update** :

In my web.config file I added this line :

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors http://subdomain.domain.com" />
```

Still no changes noticed

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. [CSP spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#ref-for-grammardef-host-char%E2%91%A1) does not allow to use IP address as host-source, except 127.0.0.1 only.
   Therefore you need to use domain name instead of IP in `<iframe src='x.x.x.x'` and in *frame-ancestors* as well.
2. If you specify hostname with scheme like http://example.com it means the default port 80 to be allowed only (or 443 for https:).
   If you use non standard port number you should to specify it exactly:
   `frame-ancestors http://subdomain.domain.com:12345` or `frame-ancestors subdomain.domain.com:12345`. The last one will allow iframing with the same scheme as parent page loaded and avoid block mixed content. But you should use multi-scheme URI: `<iframe src='//subdomain.domain.com:12345'` in this case.